# Selecting value from a row - RadGridView C#

Tags: c#, radgridview

I'm trying to get the value of a cell within a selected Row in a RadGridView, I know how to do this for a DataGridView but can't convert the code.

```
 if (rgv_customers.SelectedCells.Count > 0)
 {
     int selectedrowindex = rgv_customers.SelectedRows.RowIndex;

     DataGridViewRow selectedRow = rgv_customers.Rows[selectedrowindex];
     string comapany = Convert.ToString(selectedRow.Cells["Company"].Value);
}
```

The above code works for a DataGridView, does anyone know how to convert it for a  RadGridView?

Comment: [https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-79EsZ8fPn0](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-79EsZ8fPn0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your code must work fine!

Can you share some more code, like type of the cell or value in the cell.

If your cell `selectedRow.Cells["Company"]` is in edit mode than you should use `RadGrid.ActiveEditor.Value` otherwise your code is perfect!

Comment: glad that my answer helped you!

Comment: plz upvote if it is useful, it encourages to give more answers.